# Binding Map<string, Array<Object>> to form

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I've been trying to bind the following object to my form, but to no avail... My code is as follows:

```
    export class User {
        public Name: string;
        public Surname: string;
        public Addresses: Map<string, Array<Location>>;
   .
   .
   .
   }
```

Note the Addresses, where the key is the country and the value is an array of Location objects...

Now in my component I have something as follows, where after I load the data from the db, the update form is called to perform:

```
    this.userForm= this.fb.group({
                Name: ['', Validators.required],
                Surname: ['', Validators.required],
                Addresses: [{}],
    .
    .
    .
    });
```

UpdateForm:

```
updateForm() {
        this.userForm.patchValue({
            Name: this.user.Name,
            Surname: this.user.Surname,
            Addresses: this.user.Addresses
        });
```

Finally my html:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" novalidate>
    <div class="panel-body" >                                                                                                      
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label>Code:</label>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Addresses['UK'].Code">
                </div>
        </div>
.
.
.
```

My problem is that I cannot read the data from the specified index (UK), (or any other key) . I've also tried with Addresses.get('UK')... and Addresses.value['UK']..... but with no success... Also tried to use ngModel, but again failed. My suspicion lies into the patch call, where i think im not setting the form control properly. 
P. S. User data from db is correct, so problem lies specifically in the 'binding' part.

EDIT:
Additionally if I do a break point right after the patchValue() the userForm Addresses seems to be populated ***(from debugger)***:

```
this.userForm.get('Addresses').value

    UK:
        Code: 123
        EXT: a123
        .
        .
        .
```

My response from the db GetUser() is:

```
"Addresses": {
        "CountryCode": {
            "Code": 123,
            "Ext": "a123",
            .
            .
            .

        },
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Addresses['UK'].Code this is not your formControl hence you won't get any value from it, can you share your Addresses response. Then we need to dynamically create formControls for them.

Comment: @RohanFating i've edited the original post for more info. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your control name inside formGroup like address and same control you have to provide to you form elements like I did below

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Addresses">
```

You have to patch country code value here in this way explicitly

```
  this.userForm.patchValue({
        'Addresses': this.user.Addresses['UK'].Code
    });
```